# L2Switch Invoke IPv4Listener

Tags: ip, sdn, opendaylight, switching

Within the packethandler package of the l2switch module, I've noticed that there are a few classes (IPv4Decoder) which can process IPv4 traffic.  However whilst running the L2Switch module, they never seem to be invoked (even when an IP packet reaches the controller), and even writing something similar to the ReactiveFlowWriter doesn't seem to do anything (I'm trying to get some IP info to ajust the flow priority depending on the type of traffic).  Is it possible to get this info from l2switch?

Comment: FYI you'll perhaps get more replies on https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/l2switch-dev than here for the ODL l2switch project.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try